# How to recreate an Anchor after SceneView is paused?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I have a scene with an object attached to an Anchor node.

```
 val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()
        anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
        anchorNode?.setParent(arSceneView.scene)
```

And then I attach my objects to this anchor.

When my app goes to background(or rotate) I call:

```
 arSceneView.pause()
```

And then I don't have the anchor anymore.

What are the best practices to recreate a scene with the objects in the same position?

Should I save the AnchorNode/HitResult/Nodes in the onSaveViewState?